# applications installed via snap not running? [16.04]

Tags: unity, launcher, snap

So I just started using ubuntu less than 12 hours ago. I'm having a slough of problems, but the one I'm focusing on now I guess is when I install applications via their snaps, a) they don't show up as an installed application until i restart b) when I try to launch them, it'll look like it's about to launch then won't.

what's happening?

Comment: What happens when you install a terminal program snap like *hello-world* with `sudo snap install hello-world` and run it from the terminal with the command `hello-world` ? It should output *Hello World!*. Does it run?

Comment: Have you updated your system with update manager or "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade". What snaps aren't working? If you open a terminal and run "snap run <snapname>" what happens?

Comment: So "sudo apt-get update" isn't working either, providing the error "e: problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-invoke-success 'if usr/bin/test-w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'"